# Why is maven-war-plugin ignoring my configured filters for web resources?

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I have a filter file in `src/main/filters/base.properties` with contents:

`testProperty=testValue`

My POM has resources, filtering, and additional web resources defined (using maven-war-plugin). It also overrides the default filtering delimiter.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/base.properties</filter>
    </filters>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                <delimiters>
                    <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                </delimiters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/more-web-resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

All filtering works fine for files located in `src/main/resources`. However, a configuration file located in `src/main/more-web-resources` is not being filtered properly. So if I have a file `src/main/more-web-resources/test.properties`, with contents of:

`finalTestProperty=@testProperty@`

The final `src/main/webapp/test.properties` file looks like:

`finalTestProperty=@testProperty@`

As opposed to:

`finalTestProperty=testValue`

So, filtering just isn't working for the additional web resources specified with the maven-war-plugin. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably content of `more-web-resources` should be under `src/main/resources`.

Comment: It’s not, and it’s designed that way. Have another web resources directory allows me to use more files directly under the web app folder for different build configs. Putting them under `src/main/resources` would mean they end up in `WEB-INF/classes`, which I don’t want. I want them directly within the WAR.

Comment: the filtering is also configured within the configuration section of the war plugin. the other section in the pom is only of the resources plugin if I remember that correctly. There is a nice example in the plugin docs: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html

Comment: Try then define another resource directory: `<resource><directory>src/main/more-web-resources</directory></resource>`

Comment: I really have to duplicate the filters section inside the war plugin configuration? I’m also using the maven-properties-plugin to pull in additional filter files, so I can’t see how that would work with having to specify filters all over again inside the plugin.

Comment: The maven resources plugin is only responsible for "class loader" resources. You have to configure any other plugins that need to perform filter copying separately

Comment: I see that you have configured a custom delimiter for the maven-resources-plugin, but not for the maven-war-plugin. Could you try to set the @ delimiter also for the maven-war-plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a night of sleep, I came back to it this morning, built, and the properties are being filtered properly. I made sure my POM and project structure matches my question's exactly, and it does. It's possible I was looking at the original `test.properties` and not the built `test.properties`.

To be clear, and to address the comments in the question, I did not have to define an additional resource in the `<resources/>` section for the `more-web-resources` directory, I did not have to (re-)specify the filters in another `<filters/>` section inside the maven-war-plugin configuration, and I did not have to (re-)specify the `@` delimiter inside the maven-war-plugin. It all just works as I originally expected it to, by using the resources and filters defined in the standard sections of the POM, as well as the maven-resources-plugin.